# НЕ могу подключиться к БД на хостингу

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'host_name'@'185.53.76.77' (using password: YES)

Ловлю `Exception` такого вида. Не знаю что делать.
Пароль, пользователь и имя  и БД указаны верно.
**P.S 185.53.76.77 - не мой IP**

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске. Движок БД? Код подключения к БД? Создана ли сама БД? Назначены ли пользователю права на эту БД? IP можете проверить здесь http://www.checkip.com. Вероятно вы за NAT'ом, т.е. скорее всего он еще и динамический.

Comment: @ enzo БД - mysql
База данных, права, таблицы, всё ето есть
Я подключаюсь к этой же БД на localhost и всё хорошо
Но когда пробую подключиться к БД на удаленном сервере, тогда получаю ошибку

Comment: Значит, скорее всего, это права пользователя. Они задаются при создании. Узнайте ваш внешний IP, и посмотрите с каких хостов вам разрешено подключаться: `select host, user from mysql.user`. Попробуйте для начала подключиться к БД клиентом. Например, HeidiSQL http://www.heidisql.com/

Answer (score 2):

Настройте доступ для User: host_name с любого адреса (%)

Comment: ..на БД удалённого сервера.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте изменить права пользователя на "суперпользователь". Именно так называется поле в Postgres. Но не думаю, что если вы используете другую бд это усложнит поиск данной проперти.

Comment: эммм, зачем? лечим все проблемы в стиле `chmod 777 *`?

Comment: затем, что когда у меня была данная ошибка, я ее исправил именно таким образом, и если у вас есть другой путь решения этой проблемы, ниже есть кнопочка "дать ответ".

Comment: серьезно? Вы считаете, что работать под рутом - это решение проблемы, и его стоит советовать в качестве такового?

Comment: @AntonioK мне кажется вы забыли для чего этот форум. я знаю как решить этот вопрос таким путем, ЕСЛИ ВЫ ЗНАЕТЕ БОЛЕЕ ОПТИМАЛЬНЫЙ И ЛУЧШИЙ ВАРИАНТ, напишите свой ответ и я сам буду благодарен за то, что вы скажите как лучше сделать. а пока вашего ответа тут нету, пожалуйста, не забирайте у меня время своими вопросами, которые так любят задавать студенты матфака в свою очередь дупля не рубая в том, что говорят.